# how to get content of a page in another server

Tags: javascript, ajax

hi actually i am trying to get the content of any page which is provided...i am able to content if the page is in same server if i provide another server name its not working.i know we can easily achieve in jquery but i need it in js only... below the code i using...

```
<script>
 function loadXMLDoc()
 {
  var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {alert(xmlhttp.status);
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
    //alert("SADF");
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
     }
  var url=document.getElementById("url").value;

  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
     </script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"/>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: "i know we can easily achieve in jquery but i need it in js only" — jQuery doesn't have any features that make it significantly simpler do perform cross-domain Ajax.

Comment: Is there any error or exception??

Answer (score -1):

You cant make cross domain request from Javascript. 
There are two solutions to this;

1. Either use IFrame for this
2. Use XDomainRequest for making the request

Refer this link for more details over XDomainRequest:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767443.aspx)

Comment: Iframes have similar security restrictions to XHR, so that won't work. XDomainRequest is the non-standard solution for old-Internet Explorer, not a current solution.

Comment: No, while the accepted answer (not written by me) on the duplicate question does make mention of iframes, they are only small parts of the solutions discussed.